# What is -p in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have this in my `package.json`:

```
 build:prod
    SET NODE_ENV=prod && webpack -p
```

What does `-p` mean?

I have looked at the webpack documentation, but couldn't find anything for it.

Thanks.

Comment: [Didn't look hard enough](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/cli#production-shortcut--p)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `p` flag stands for Production. It will perform the following steps:

- Minification using UglifyJsPlugin
- Runs the LoaderOptionsPlugin
- Sets the NodeJS environment variable triggering certain packages to compile differently

[Read more about it here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/).